# Datos repetidos c# datagridview

Tags: c#

Tengo este código el cual lo ejecuto para eliminar datos repetidos de un *DataGridView*, pero tiene un problema: me arroja un dato de más.

```
int m = 0;  
int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;  
int k;
string estaFila, unaFila;

while (m < n)
{
    k = 1;
    estaFila = String.Empty;

    // Relleno la cadena con los datos de toda la fila
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        estaFila = String.Concat(estaFila,dataGridView1.Rows[m].Cells[i].Value.ToString());

    while (k < n)
    {
        unaFila = String.Empty;  
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            unaFila = 
   String.Concat(unaFila,dataGridView1.Rows[k].Cells[i].Value.ToString());

        if (String.Compare(estaFila, unaFila) == 0 && k != m)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(k); 
            n--;     
        }
        k++;
    }
    m++;
}
```

El *DataGridView* inicialmente es así:

```
0005    18/10/2019 |
0012    17/10/2019 |
3067    17/10/2019 |
3067    17/10/2019 |
3067    17/10/2019 |
3067    17/10/2019 |
3067    17/10/2019 |
```

Pero cuando ejecuto el código queda así (me trae un dato repetido aún):

```
0005    18/10/2019 |
0012    17/10/2019 |
**3067  17/10/2019 |
3067    17/10/2019**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo es que, cuando finaliza el ciclo, dejas fuera el último renglón (`m < n`). Para hacerlo de esa manera, lo correcto sería `m <= n` o bien, desde donde la declaras:

```
int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Count
```

(ojo: solo una de las dos opciones, no ambas).

Explicado eso, yo te recomendaría que uses las funciones que ya te proporciona .Net:

```
DataView dv = new DataView((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv.ToTable(true, "num", "fecha");

// "true" es para indicarle que sean registros distintos,
// de ahí en adelante, colocas uno a uno el nombre de las columnas que quieras mostrar
// en el DataGridView.
```